# Google map with Flutter Mobile Web, how can i move camera with one finger?

Tags: flutter, google-maps, web, mobile, gesture

I made a Flutter web application with google map api. It work well in PC. But in Mobile, it request double finger for move camera. How can i move camera with one fingure?
I kept searching the internet but couldn't get a proper answer.

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the issue you have specified? But from what I know, panning works fine with just one finger on google maps flutter mobile sample apps.